# AngularFire 2 is not updating in real time

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have this code in AngularJS 2:

```
    @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
     providers: [ItemService],
     })
     export class AppComponent  implements OnInit{
      items : FirebaseListObservable<any>;
      constructor(public itemService: ItemService) {
     }
     ngOnInit(){
      this.items =  this.itemService.getAll();
     }
     save(contenido:string,programador:string , horas: number) {
     let postIt = new PostIt(contenido,programador,horas);
     this.itemService.save(postIt);
     }
      title = 'Lista de tareas';
   }
```

He is the service:

```
 @Injectable()    
 export class ItemService {
   constructor(public af: AngularFire) {}
   getAll(): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
     return this.af.database.list('/items');
   }
   save(medicamento : PostIt){    
     this.af.database.list('/items').push(medicamento);
   }
 }
```

The `PostIt` class with getters is here:

```
 export class PostIt {
   private _contenido: string;
   private _programador: string;
   private _horas : number;
 }
```

And finally, the HTML template:

```
  *ngFor="let item of items | async"
```

I read all the AngularFire documentation, but I opened two browsers, added a new task in the first one, and it doesn't update in the other.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see the items you add in Firebase ?

Comment: Yes yes, they are added into firebase, and if I refresh they are on the second browser list too, but no realtime feature, even if I use FirebaseObservables.